# drupal 7 vs vs Wordpress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal

Looking to develop a tuition website where the tutors can update their profile anytime. What are the advantages of using Drupal or Wordpress over pure PHP code?

I have vast experience buidling PHP from ground but CMS might have something for me?

Comment: [tuition](http://www.answers.com/topic/tuition) [tutorial](http://www.answers.com/topic/tutorial) [tutoring](http://www.answers.com/topic/tutoring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question as stated is a little subjective, but speaks to the more general software engineering principle of software reuse.  In a nutshell, the advantage of using a CMS is that most of the work is already completed and tested.  The disadvantage is it may not have been done to your liking, but even then, customization is usually easier than starting from scratch.  The relative advantages of different CMSes, however, is really off topic for this site.